# Passing both <Vec<Value>> and <Vec<&Value>> as arguments to a function

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
        match media_objects {
            Some(media_obj) => {
                let filtered_media_obj = media_obj
                    .iter()
                    .filter(|&mo| {
                        media_ks
                            .iter()
                            .any(|mk| mo["media_key"].as_str().unwrap() == mk.as_str().unwrap())
                    })
                    .collect::<Vec<&Value>>();
                store_all_media(&pool, tweet_id, filtered_media_obj).await?;
            }
            None => {
                let fake_media_obj = media_ks
                    .iter()
                    .map(|mk| {
                        json!({
                            "media_key": mk.as_str().unwrap()
                        })
                    })
                    .collect::<Vec<Value>>();

                // todo ugly
                let fake_media_obj_2 = fake_media_obj.iter().map(|mo| mo).collect::<Vec<&Value>>();

                store_all_media(&pool, tweet_id, fake_media_obj_2).await?;
            }
        }
```

The issue is that `store_all_media` expects a `<Vec<&Value>>`:

```
pub async fn store_all_media(
    pool: &PgPool,
    tweet_id: &str,
    media_objects: Vec<&Value>,
) -> Result<(), sqlx::error::Error>;
```

The first leg of the match statement correctly produces that, but the second leg, because it's generating `json!()` on the fly, produces `<Vec<Value>>`, which I can't pass to the store function.

I've come up with a dirty workaround, but I'm wondering what's the right way to do this? Do I:

- somehow change `Value` to `&Value` in the second leg?
- change the type the function accepts to `<Vec<Value>>` and then try to coerce the first leg?
- try to use trait bounds?
- try to use trait objects?

Sorry if this is obvious to the more experienced out there, as a newcommer from dynamic languages this feels like a big challenge:)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the exact needs of `store_all_media`, one option might be to use `&[T] where T: Borrow<V>`:

- `Vec` trivially derefs to `&[]`
- being generic over `Borrow<V>` means the method can accept both `V`s and `&V`s, in fact that's one use-case for `Borrow` as it has blanket implementations of `Borrow<&T> for T` and `Borrow<&T> for &T`.

Comment: Small technicality: The blanket impls are of `Borrow<T>` (and not `Borrow<&T>`) for both `T` and `&T`. If `Q : Borrow<R>`, then a value of type `Q` can be borrowed as a `&R`. In other words, [`<Q as Borrow<R>>::borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#tymethod.borrow) returns `&R` and not `R`.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. I've been playing with your proposal on playground and I can't get it to work. Here's my best attempt - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33cb26e6c085e38e18b4168213ffcd4d - could you take a look and see what I'm missing?